# Doctrine throw exception with getOneOrNullResult

Tags: doctrine-orm

Doctrine throw Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException, with this code:

```
$qb->select('a')
   ->from('TblGames', 'a')
   ->leftJoin('a.categories', 'b')
   ->leftJoin('a.user', 'c')
   ->where("a.gamId = $gid");
   ->andWhere("a.gamStatus = '1'");

$game = $qb->getQuery()->setHydrationMode(Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Even when i tried to change ->getResult return only 1 result.

---

**Answer: it is my mistake : $qb->select('a, b, c')**

Comment: This question is unclear, please explain what you are trying to get and the approaches and results you have already tried. It is not up to the stackoverflow standard. Please correct or remove

Answer (score 13):

You have to use setMaxResults(1)

Comment: I am looking for solution of this too, but this looks realy weird. Why Doctrine automaticaly does not return first result as I expect?